# Retain value in a loop

Tags: sas

I have a series of values in a column -- the first value is a category description, the different categories are separated by a blank row.  In the example below the first category is called A, second category is called T, and third category is called R.

What I want to do is to retain the first instance of the category name and create a new field name prefaced by the category.  See the have/want below.  Any ideas?

For example:

```
data example;
   input have $1. want $4.;
   datalines;
A    
T A_T
G A_G

T    
R T_R
E T_E
W T_W

R    
H R_H
R R_R
;
```

Comment: I notice you used the word 'retain' in your title.  This also happens to be one of the SAS keywords you could use to achieve this.  Have you already tried to write code using the `retain` statement and failed?  If so, can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should consider using `retain` statement in SAS to carry the values over and `lag` statement to determine when you need to reset your retained value.

```
data have;
    input category $1.;
    datalines;
A    
T
G

T  
R
E
W

R    
H
R
;

data want (drop=category_retained);
    set have;
    length subcategory $3.;
    retain category_retained "";

    if lag(category) = "" then
        do;
            subcategory = "";
            category_retained = category;
        END;

    if lag(category) ne "" and category ne "" then
        do;
            subcategory = CATX("_",category_retained,category);
        END;
RUN;
```